# Non Editable element in TinyMCE (related to Mathjax)

Tags: tinymce, mathjax

I'm building an extended editor around TinyMCE and I have to implement a Math formula module. I've choosen Mathjax for formula rendering, using plain html/css. So far, I've managed to create a plugin that popup a panel with a textarea, you can enter your latex in, there's a preview in the panel.

Once you validate the formula, it's injected into tinymce content. This new content is A LOT of spans with inlined styles, and OF COURSE, I don't want tinymce to be able to edit that directly. (sidenote: we only store latex, not the rendered html output from mathjax)

Basically, I want that a piece of html inside Tinymce to be ignored totally, but displayed in place. I want my carret to be able to move before that piece of html, and after, but not inside.
The "non editable content" plugin seems to be close of what I'm looking for, but it has some limitation (you can't ADD no editable content on the fly, having nested html content inside an element flagged as "non editable" broke some things, etc.)

Is someone could help with that ? I started to tweak the non editable plugin, but it's really really hard to understand existing code. Has someone already did something like that, or is there another third party plugin ?

thanks

Comment: Not an answer but a word of caution -- the MathJax HTML-CSS output depends heavily on the client, with everything from browser version to user style sheets to system fonts affecting the output code. Storing the input format or the intermediary MathML (and rendering it with MathJax)  is a much better choice.

Comment: I did not mention it, but of course, we do not store mathjax rendering. When saving our tinymce content, we only store Latex strings, that are rendered on the client with mathjax.